# How do I get the contents of the H3 tag from the LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list that contains a bunch of li's. I need to loop through these li's and get the text inside the h3 where it says Community in the following html.

For example I can loop through li's like so:

```
$('#subpanel_list li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('div').children('table').children('h3').html());
});
```

But I cant get the value `Community`. How do I get the that value from the following mess of html that is inside the `li` using jQuery?

```
<li class="noBullet" id="whole_subpanel_accounts_accounts_1">
    <div id="subpanel_title_accounts_accounts_1" onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'move';" style="cursor: move;">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="formHeader h3Row">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="">
                        <h3>
                            <span>
                                <a name="accounts_accounts_1"/>
                                    <span id="show_link_accounts_accounts_1" style="display: none;">
                                        <span id="hide_link_accounts_accounts_1" style="">
                                            Community
                                        </span>
                        </h3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100%">
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div cookie_name="accounts_accounts_1_v" id="subpanel_accounts_accounts_1" style="">
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text than use `text()` and not `html()`. The h3 is a descendent of the li, so using closest is wrong.Closest goes in the opposite direction, so you are looking at the ancestors. You need to use `find()`.

```
$(this).find("h3").text()
```

Answer (score 2):

`closest()` goes up the DOM tree, whereas you appear to want to go down it. Try using `find()` instead:

```
$('#subpanel_list li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('div').children('table').children('h3').html());
});
```

Note that you can also shorten this selector to a single `find()`:

```
$(this).find('div table h3').html()
```

You may also be better using the `text()` method instead of `html()` as you state that you only want the `Community` value, not the encoded HTML too.

Finally, you appear to have several unclosed HTML elements, although I assume this is just an issue when transcribing the example for the question.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` rather than `closest()`, and you can simplify your chained `children()`:

```
$(this).find('div > table h3').html()
```